# MacTex 2012Basic cannot find installed packages

Tags: packages, texlive, mactex, latexian

In an attempt to save valuable space on a 128GB SSD drive, I endeavored to replace my full 2012 MacTex texlive install (>3.5GB) with 2012Basic (270MB!).  I understand that packages are not installed by default.  Using `tlmgr`, I installed several of the packages my .tex document calls for.  They are installed by `tlmgr` in `/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex`.  This is very similar to where the full texlive installs packages.  However, my GUI (LaTeXian) fails to complile the document (fails to locate packages...).

- I ran `texhash` (both as root and as my user)
- I tried playing around with paths in `texmf.cnf`
- I created a symbolic link from `~/Library/texmf` to `/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex`
- I tried adding the package location to `$PATH` (seems like a messy hack...)

No dice.  The `texmf.cnf` file points to `~/Library/texmf`, but so does the `texmf.cnf` in the full install... And, I'd prefer to let `tlmgr` handle the packages rather than install manually in `~/Library/texmf`

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `kpsewhich article.cls` return?  Also `kpsewhich` for a package you just installed.  Do basic documents compile properly for you (i.e. ones that don't use the extra packages you installed)?

Comment: @AlanMunn: basic docs do compile.  `kpsewhich article.cls` returns `/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls`  Trying `kpsewhich amsmath` (which exists in as `../text-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty` returns nothing (not "bad command", simply nothing).

Comment: @jjwebster Try `kpsewhich amsmath.sty`...

Comment: d'oh.  `kpsewhich amsmath.sty` gives `/usr/local/texlive/2012basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty` Does this mean the problem lies with my GUI?  If so, why does it work with the full texlive install... but not basic (simply by flipping the current texlive instance in System Prefs?)

Comment: It's possible that LaTeXian has hard coded paths and that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, this is odd.  With the basic texlive install active, I attempted to build the document that fails in LaTeXian from the command line using `pdflatex <docname>.tex`... and it worked (at least compiled as far as the packages I had manually installed)  Now LaTeXian works.  I can't explain it, but hopefully this helps someone stuck with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Based on the last comment, this is not reproducible so I guess goes down as 'unclear'.